# Linux shell one-liner for scripting multiple CURL downloads

Tags: curl, command-line

This line extracts the number of WiFi clients connected to the router number one (note the `8081` port):

```
luis@balanceador:~$ curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8081 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c
7
```

this is for router number 2 (note the `8082` port):

```
luis@balanceador:~$ curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8082 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c
12
```

and for number n:

```
curl -s http://192.168.6.100:808n | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c
```

And the sum of 1 and 2 :

```
luis@balanceador:~$ echo $(( $(curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8081 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c)+$(curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8082 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c)  ))
19
```

So, as I would like to know the number of WiFi clients for all my 9 routers:

```
echo $(( Router1+Router2+...+RouterN ))

echo $(( $(curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8081 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c)+$(curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8082 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c)+$(curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8083 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c)+$(curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8084 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c)+$(curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8085 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c)+$(curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8086 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c)+$(curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8087 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c)+$(curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8088 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c)+$(curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8089 | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c) ))
```

Isn't there a better way to program some **one-liner** for this on Linux Command-line?

Comment: If you want it easy,make a script from your code called `rtrCount`; then you have much less typing and no place for copy/paste errors to creep in. And ... why the obsession with 1 liners!? ;-) They limit your ability in the long run to create better solutions as your understanding of programming increases. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 9; i=i+1 )); do curl -s http://192.168.6.100:808$i | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c ; done | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Here is how it works:

### For

We start with making use of your `and for number n:` example:

```
curl -s http://192.168.6.100:808n | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c
```

and revised it to work within a C-style for-loop. The C-style for-loop syntax looks like this, for example if you wanted to echo a number `2` for 9 times you can do:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 9; i=i+1 )); do echo 2 ; done
```

So to integrate your example to work within the body of a for-loop (replacing the `echo 2` part above):

```
curl -s http://192.168.6.100:808$i | grep "eth1" -i | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -io | grep "eth1" -c
```

- bash will replace `$i` with the iteration number in our for-loop.
- thus the first iteration the command will start with: `curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8081 ...`
- iteration 2, the command will start with: `curl -s http://192.168.6.100:8082 ...` and so on until all 9 routers have been done

### Awk

Next, `awk` program can be used to calculate the sum of a column of numbers, for example we can simulate the output of 1 and 3 on separate lines, passed to awk:

```
echo -e '1\n3' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Result: `4`

- the `$1` is the first "field" in terms of the multi-line input `awk` receives
- the `s+=` adds the value to a variable we call `s` . You could have also called it something else such as `mysum` but I prefer `s` to keep it short
- `awk` does this through each line
- `print s` outputs the final value of `s` which holds the sum

### Putting it together

`... done | awk ...` simply pipes the multi-line output from the for-loop, and passes it to  the `awk` program, so that `awk` program can calculate the final sum you wanted.

Comment: Tested working fine. Thanks you for the detailed explanations.

Comment: With no hurry, but the best of the answers that fit will be accepted. I prefer to allow some time for more answers or editions, precissions and comments to help evaluate the existing answers. Rules don't oppose to this behavior of me, and many users re-edit their answers even weeks after they wrote them. The info will still be there, even without the acceptation mark, so I see no reason to hurry up.

Answer (score 1):

Not a one-liner, but some structure:

```
count_clients () {
    curl -s http://192.168.6.100:$1 | grep "setWirelessTable" -i | grep "eth1" -c
}
sum=0
for n in {8001..8009}; do
    (( sum += $(count_clients $n) ))
done
echo $sum
```

It looks like you have a lot of redundant `grep "eth1"` calls in your pipeline